# No appenders could be found for logger warning even after specifying log properties in classpath

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have to perform basic logging on my application for which I am using Log4j. I have set up `log.properties` file inside resource folder with desired configuration but am getting the following warning when I try to log information

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.MyClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

This is my property file located under resource folder :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, ERROR, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=./resources/application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This is what my project structure looks like :

> src
>   -> main
>
> ```
> -> java
>        ....
>
> -> resources
>
>
>        --> log.properties
> ```

Every folder is present in java build path of the project as well.

This is how am calling just to test:

```
public class Demo {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Demo.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.debug("demo");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u try to rename the file to log4j.properties and also

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,ERROR stdout, file
```

line should have either debug or error not both